# Getting ERROR unexpected token in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Hi I developing a web app using spring mvc 3 and hibernate 4. I'm using annotations for all config.

When I try to select a entity I get an error:

```
DaoException: unexpected token: MEMBER near line 1, column 37 [from clanwar.model.ClanMember where MEMBER = :member]
at clanwar.dao.impl.ClanMemberDao.findByPlayerId(ClanMemberDao.java:71)
```

If I do the query with `.createSQLQuery()` hibernate return me an `Object[]` instance of `ClanMember` entity.

Method in DAO:

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional

    ...

    @Override
    public ClanMember findByPlayerId(int id) throws DaoException {

        ClanMember foundMember;

        try {
            foundMember = (ClanMember) getSession()
                .createQuery("from ClanMember where MEMBER = :member")
                .setParameter("member", id)
                .uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return foundMember;
    }

    ...
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLAN_MEMBERS")
public class ClanMember implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLAN")
    private Clan clan;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER")
    private Player member;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE")
    private ClanRole role;

    public ClanMember() {}

    // Setters and getters

}
```

Table CLAN_MEMBERS:

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CLAN   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| MEMBER | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ROLE   | int(11) | NO   |     | 1       |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try use alias `from ClanMember cm where cm.member.id = :member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member` is a reserved word in HQL. Escape it by adding a table alias.

Also, since `member` is of type `Player`, when your `where clause` contains `member` you need to provide a parameter of type `Player`. Alternatively if you want to provide the ID as you're doing, you need to explicitly search for the `id`:

So either:

```
 foundMember = (ClanMember) getSession()
            .createQuery("from ClanMember c where c.member = :member")
            .setParameter("member", someInstanceOfPlayer);
            .uniqueResult();
```

or

```
 foundMember = (ClanMember) getSession()
            .createQuery("from ClanMember c where c.member = :member")
            .setParameter("member", idOfAPlayer);
            .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I don't know member is a reserved word. I add the alias and all work (I getting another exception but this is other aswer). Thanks @geert3

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like following:

```
from ClanMember where member = :member
```

Therefore your code to get member should look like following:

```
foundMember = (ClanMember) getSession()
                .createQuery("from ClanMember where member = :member")
                .setParameter("member", id)
                .uniqueResult();
```

And also note that `id` which you pass should be an instance of `Player` class.

Comment: This query looks like my query but with MEMBER to member. (Only the uppercase can throw this error). I change and I getting the same error. @DarshanLila

Comment: member is the field of your class in hibernate you need to use that and not the table columns while writting the query.